# Why the warning: "Constant <name> inferred to have type (), which may be unexpected"?

Tags: sorting, swift3

I'm attempting to sort an array of instantiated items of the class: "Employees".

However I'm getting the following error within my playground:

[image]

Here's the code as written in my playground:

```
class Employee {
    var firstName:String = ""
    var lastName:String = ""
    init(fName:String, lName:String) {
        self.firstName = fName
        self.lastName = lName
    }
}

var employees = [Employee]()

// 1)
var employee = Employee(fName: "Ric", lName: "Lee")
employees.append(employee)

// 2)
employee = Employee(fName: "Ralph", lName: "Knott")
employees.append(employee)

// 3)
employee = Employee(fName: "Joe", lName: "Smirf")
employees.append(employee)

// 4)
employee = Employee(fName: "Meredith", lName: "Lind")
employees.append(employee)

// 5)
employee = Employee(fName: "Aarnald", lName: "Zingerhost")
employees.append(employee)

let sortedEmployees = employees.sort { (e1:Employee, e2:Employee) -> Bool in
    e1.lastName < e2.lastName
}
```

What am I missing here? 
Why the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you are using the wrong function (former `sortInPlace`):

In **Swift 3**

- `sort()` has been renamed to `sorted()`
- `sortInPlace()` has been renamed to  `sort()`

Therefore it's

```
let sortedEmployees = employees.sorted { (e1:Employee, e2:Employee) -> Bool in
    e1.lastName < e2.lastName
}
```

Source: [Swift Evolution: Apply API Guidelines to the Standard Library](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md)

Answer (score 1):

try declaring

```
let sortedEmployees = employees.sort { (e1:Employee, e2:Employee) -> Bool in
e1.lastName < e2.lastName}
```

as

```
let sortedEmployees : () = employees.sort { (e1:Employee, e2:Employee) -> Bool in
e1.lastName < e2.lastName}
```

Comment: The type annotation suppresses the warning but does not return anything because it's the wrong function.

Comment: It wasn't an error, it was a warning. But once again, `sort` is the wrong function. See my answer.